# Drawing tangents for a bezier curve in OpenGL using c++

Tags: c++, opengl, point, bezier, curve

So I have a program that has 4 control points

```
std::vector<ControlPoint> cam_pos_points;
    cam_pos_points.push_back(ControlPoint(-0.79, 0.09, 0.2, 0));
    cam_pos_points.push_back(ControlPoint(-0.88, -0.71, 0.2, 1));
    cam_pos_points.push_back(ControlPoint(1.3, -0.8, 0.2, 2));
    cam_pos_points.push_back(ControlPoint(0.71, 0.76, 0.2, 3));
```

Basically, what happens is that I've set up a way to move my control points and when a control point is moved, the new position is saved and the curve is re-calculated based on this new position. The way I'm drawing the curve is I'm using these equations:

```
for (double t = 0; t < 1; t += 0.1){
    float Px =(pow((1 - t), 3) * cam_pos_points[0].positionx()) + 
        ((pow((1 - t), 2) * t) * cam_pos_points[1].positionx()) + 
        (((1 - t) * pow(t, 2)) * cam_pos_points[2].positionx()) + 
        (pow(t, 3) * cam_pos_points[3].positionx());

    float Py =(pow((1 - t), 3) * cam_pos_points[0].positiony()) + 
        ((pow((1 - t), 2) * t) * cam_pos_points[1].positiony()) + 
        (((1 - t) * pow(t, 2)) * cam_pos_points[2].positiony()) + 
        (pow(t, 3) * cam_pos_points[3].positiony());
}
```

And then using these two float values, I put them into vec3's and make a bunch of points. I then draw a line between all these points by putting them into a multiline class by declaring what points will be in the curve and then drawing a straight line between each point. The end result will be a bezier curve.

The problem I'm having right now is drawing the tangents for the bezier curve. My idea was that for the first control point, was to say the tangent is on the line P1 - P2. So after drawing the tangent, when I move the tangent point, what equations am I supposed to use to re-draw the shape of the curve? I've already found the derivatives of the bezier curve equation but I don't know what to do with them:

```
float dx = (-3*(pow((1 - t), 2)) * cam_pos_points[0].positionx()) + 
             (((-2*(1 - t)) * t) * cam_pos_points[1].positionx()) + 
              (((1 - t) * (2*t)) * cam_pos_points[2].positionx()) + 
                  ((3*pow(t, 2)) * cam_pos_points[3].positionx());

float dy = (-3*(pow((1 - t), 2)) * cam_pos_points[0].positiony()) + 
             (((-2*(1 - t)) * t) * cam_pos_points[1].positiony()) + 
              (((1 - t) * (2*t)) * cam_pos_points[2].positiony()) + 
                  ((3*pow(t, 2)) * cam_pos_points[3].positiony());
```

Comment: why use `pow` instead of just direct computation? `float mt = 1-t, t2 = t*t, mt2 = mt * mt, t3 = t2*t, mt3=mt2*mt;` and then use those. Shave some overhead off. On that note: I don't know what you're computing, but it's not a Bezier curve. A cubic bezier takes the form `a * (t-1)^3 + b * 3 * t * (t-1)^2 + c * 3 * (t-1) * t^2 + d * t^3` where a, b, c, and d are your coordinates. Head on over to https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#control and read through the first few sections to make sure you got the maths right. Right now: you haven't.

Answer (score 0):

You starting tangent will be from the first control point to the second, and the ending tangent will be from the fourth control point to the third. I'd suggest you start fresh each time you redraw it; i.e., whenever a control point moves, treat it as an all-new equation.

In the case that one (or both) of your tangents are zero-length, then they aren't actually tangents *per se* but the curve will go toward the opposite endpoint.

That's why you can use a Bezier section with no tangents to represent a straight line.

Comment: Well that's what I'm doing with control points. Everytime a control point is moved, the entire curve is re-calculated. With tangents, when a tangent point is moved, I want the angle or the shape of the curve to be adjusted without moving any control points. The problem I'm having is that I'm determining where the tangents will lie after I've calculated the curve so moving the tangents will do nothing. Is there something I can do to calculate the curve using the tangent points so I can re-calculate it when I move the tangents?

Answer (score 0):

The equations are wrong.

The correct equation is

```
(1-t)^3 * p0 + 3*(1-t)^2*t * p1 + 3*(1-t)*t^2 * p2 + t^3 * p3.
```

expand and differentiate to get the tangents.

Comment: When you say expand and differentiate, do you mean just take the derivative of that equation and plugging in certain t values will give me the tangents?

Comment: So I found the derivative of that equation but I don't know what to do with it. Is the number a position or a direction and if it's a direction, how can I turn it into a control point that I can modify?

Comment: Exactly. Expand, and you get two cubic equations, one in x and one in y, with t the independent variable. Take dx/dt and dy/dt to get two quadratics, using elementary calculus,  then plug in t to get the direction of the tangent at a point, given t.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you want to draw the tangent points for the tangent vector at the start and end of the Bezier curve so that you can allow users to adjust the curve's shape by moving the tangent points. If this is the case, you need to be aware that moving the tangent points will also move the 2nd or the 3rd control points. So, the correct procedure would be to re-calculate the 2nd or the 3rd control point from the moved tangent points, then redraw the curve.

For cubic Bezier curve, the C'(t) at t=0 and 1 is

> C'(0)=3*(P1-P0) 
>  C'(1)=3*(P3-P2)

Let's assume your tangent point for the starting tangent is T0 and is located at

> T0= P0+s0*C'(0)=P0+3*s0*(P1-P0)

where s0 is a constant scale factor for making sure your tangent point will not be located too far away from the control points. When T0 is changed to T0*, you can update the control point P1 as

> P1* = (T0*-P0)/(3*s0)+P0.

Do similar update for control point P2 when the tangent point of the end tangent is moved. Then, you can redraw your curve.

Comment: So are control points different from tangents? People have said to find the tangent you have to calculate the derivative which makes me think it's different from the control points but by moving the tangent if you're also moving the control points, is there any difference between moving the tangent and moving the control points or is the tangent just an easier way to move the control points?

Comment: @OP:  A cubic Bezier curve is represented by 4 control points. So, its first derivatives (or tangents) can also be represented in terms of these 4 control points. So. moving the tangent is just an indirect way of moving the corresponding control point.